# Trouble dealing with "next_sibling" in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to understand the practical usage of `next_sibling` in `BeautifulSoup`. I've searched a lot but could not find examples that can satisfy my requirement. However, If i try to get the `text` within the 2nd `td` tag starting from the first `tr` using `next_sibling`. I've tried a way but it gives me error. Hope somebody can help me on this. Thanks.

Elements:

```
html_content="""
<tr>
    <td>Not this one</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>There it is!!</td>
</tr>
"""
```

I tried like below but it throws error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")
item = soup.find("tr").next_sibling.find("td").text
print(item)
```

Once again my intention is to parse `There it is!!` starting from first `tr` tag and using `next_sibling`. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the error being thrown please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem tha you're searching for [`find_next_sibling()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
item = soup.find("tr").find_next_sibling().find('td').text
```